# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, ajax, syntax-error

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I want to display the users online on specific rooms only.

the code below is the function that calls my online.php this is under my chat.php
when I load the page this function also loads.

```
function whos_online() {
  if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "online.php?room=<?php $_SESSION['room']?>", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  document.getElementById("whos_online").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
}
```

ONLINE.PHP

this is the content of my online.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'db.inc.php';

    class WhosOnline{
        $rn = $_GET['room'];
        protected $get_status_query = "SELECT * FROM `online_users` WHERE `room` = '{$rn}'";
        public function DisplayUsers(){
            $get_current_status = mysql_query( $this->get_status_query );
            if( mysql_num_rows( $get_current_status ) != 0 ) {
                while( $row_status = mysql_fetch_array( $get_current_status ) ) {
                    if( $_SESSION['username'] == true ) {
                        echo "<div class='online_margin'>
                                <b>".base64_decode($row_status['username'])."</b>
                              </div>
                              <hr style='border: 0; border-top: solid 1px #D8D8D8;margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;' />";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $Online = new WhosOnline;
    $Online->DisplayUsers();
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: You made a type somewhere, look in the neighborhood of the error and see if there is a syntax error.

Comment: what do you mean by type?. the error points out to $rn = $_GET['room']; and i dont know why.

Comment: This is not how you should do it. Ever.

Comment: Should have been typo.  And you can not have code inside a class, only within a method of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, even this gives an error:

```
class WhosOnline{
    public $rn = $_GET['room'];
}
```

This also gives an error:

```
$v = "Hi there";
class WhosOnline{
    public $rn = $v;
}
```

The error is because you're trying to set a variable based on another variable in the class definition. You could do this in the constructor. Or you can set class members based on CONSTANTS (as you were doing with the query string). But why not rewrite your WhosOnline method like this:

```
public function DisplayUsers(){
    $get_current_status = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM `online_users` WHERE `room` = '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['room']) . "'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($get_current_status)!=0){
        while($row_status = mysql_fetch_array($get_current_status)){
            if($_SESSION['username']==true){
                echo "<div class='online_margin'>   <b>".base64_decode($row_status['username'])."</b></div><hr style='border: 0; border-top:  solid 1px #D8D8D8;margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;' />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will also remove any potential errors you might have with `$this->` references missing.

Comment: I tried implementing your code. And it says call to undefined function sanitize()

Comment: on my original post it points out to online.php line number 10

Comment: Ah, sorry - I copied that from above. But that's a separate error. As they say above, that's for the reader to implement ;-) Rather use mysql_safe_string(..). Made the change.

Comment: Call to undefined function mysql_safe_string()

when I tried the mysql_safe_string

Comment: Good grief- sorry, far too late at night. The function is mysql_real_escape_string(..)

Comment: thanks so much. I finally solved the problem using your solution.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $rn = $_GET['room'];
> protected $get_status_query = "SELECT * FROM `online_users` WHERE `room` =     '{$rn}'";
> ```

This is a bad habit that you need to break **RIGHT NOW**.

```
protected function get_status_query($rn) {
  return "SELECT * FROM `online_users` WHERE `room` =     '". sanitize($rn) . "'";
};
```

Implementation of `sanitize()` is left to the reader.

Comment: I tried to replace according to your correction

now I am getting an sql error
mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: You couldn't take the time to answer his question in this post? Great point about injection vulnerability, but this isn't an answer...

Comment: @orourkek: You're right. It's not an answer. It's a *solution*.

Comment: I agree that it's obviously something that has to be learned, but the actual answer is so darn simple that it just seems silly not to include it. In any case @user1232117, the answer to your question is below, but you should **definitely** follow this advice as well.

Comment: Your approach isn't that much better. Don't build queries this way. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @orourkek im sorry sir im just new in coding. where can i find it sir?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sir I cant figure out why it returns an sql_error.

Answer (score 2):

you could not initialized any variable directly in class , try this

```
public $rn;
protected $get_status_query;

public __construct(){
      $this->rn = $_GET['room'];
      $this->get_status_query = "SELECT * FROM `online_users` WHERE `room` = '{$this->rn}'";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but only with a fixed value like `3` or `"I am a string"`

Comment: @zombaya I mean the post variables and initialization of query

Comment: Maybe add the initialization in a constructor.